# selecting from <td python -selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I give up, i cant find the solution, so i will ask here, thank you.

After i perform a double click i have 2 options: "drept" and "restrictie".

After pressing "drept":

```
\<td role="gridcell" tabindex="0" class="a-GV-cell u-tS is-changed" xpath="1" aria-labelledby="RIGHTS_ig_grid_vc_ctx RIGHTS_ig_grid_vc_cur" id="RIGHTS_ig_grid_vc_cur"\>Drept\</td\>

::before

"Drept" ==$0
```

After pressing "restrictie":

```
\<td role="gridcell" tabindex="0" class="a-GV-cell u-tS is-changed" xpath="1" aria-labelledby="RIGHTS_ig_grid_vc_ctx RIGHTS_ig_grid_vc_cur" id="RIGHTS_ig_grid_vc_cur"\>Restrictie\</td\>

::before

"Restrictie"
```

How can i perform the action?thank you!

didn't try because double click doesnt work on this!

Comment: _How can i perform the action?_ Which action are you trying to perform exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to press double click and select "drept" or "restricție".

Comment: Update the question with your attempts to `double click`?